# Image processing for a white object within a black background python

Tags: python, opencv

So I have this kind of pictures [dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ekpM.jpg), I want to process this image in order to get a very clear white borders. I did this processing but the result is this [image processed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02aGH.png)

```
image = cv2.imread('pictures/1.bmp')
ImgBlur = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (11, 11), 0)
imgCanny = cv2.Canny(ImgBlur, 100, 100)
```

I want the picture to be more clear in borders and without white points in the inside.
Can someone suggest me what type of processing can bring better results?

Comment: you can try this one [Hough Line Transform](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html)

Answer (score 0):

*want the picture to be more clear in borders*

I suggest giving a try [Erosion and Dilatation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/df6/tutorial_erosion_dilatation.html) and combination thereof.